# Wrong parameters for ESPG:42304?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, parameters

I need to use the Lambert Conformal Conic for Natural Resources Canada EPSG:42304, which I could not find in QGIS 2.10.1 CRS list. I located the proj4 parameters on-line from three locations, all of which were the same:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

But when I add this and test it in the Custom Coordinate Reference System Definition a pop up comes with a warning saying 'Northing and Easting must be in decimal form'.

I have tried looking around for an answer or a different set of parameters, but to no avail.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: At a first glance it seems correct. Just in case, have you tried adding .0 (e.g. +lat_1=49.0 ) at the end of each numerical value ?

Answer (score 2):

The warning saying 'Northing and Easting must be in decimal form' doesn't have anything to do with the Proj4 params. You're getting that error as you are either:

1. not putting anything in the test North/East fields, or
2. putting non-numeric values in (i.e a coordinate in degrees, minutes, seconds)

and then clicking calculate.

You don't *have* to test. Just leave the North/East fields blank, *don't* click calculate, only click OK and the custom CRS will be created/available.

Comment: Thanks for this - not clicking calculate still lets you add the custom CRS